Lightdm: Configure path for autologin-home directories / avoid conflicts with snaps
I want to configure lightdm for autologin and anonymous guest sessions. The configuration works as wanted: After each computer startup a new home-directory /tmp/guest-user-... is created for the user.
After beeing auto-logged-in, one is hit by a well known problem: snap-applications cannot be started: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 because snap accepts home directories under /home only. It is possible to override the homedir-path in snap (snap set system homedirs=/tmp), but /tmp is not accepted. /tmp is a reserved directory for snap.
My question is: Can lightdm be configured to create the temporary home-directories below a different directory than /tmp ? E.g. /tmp2)
Thanks a lot
Martin

I don't have a lightdm based system to test, but looking at the guest-account.sh script, add_account creates the homedir using mktemp - and mktemp should honor the TMPDIR environment variable. HOWEVER it appears to be hard-wired to generate the guest username from that by removing a leading /tmp/ so you'd need to address that as well.

Thanks, your comment was helpful to me. For now, I decides to use mint 22 for the guest-account purpose. Mint 22 does not use snaps. So no problems with temporary home directories below /tmp .
